# Can I change the same filter in multiple reports quickly?

Tags: tfs-reports

We have about 10 tfs reports around work items that filter on "Iteration Path" multiple times. Every sprint we have to make 25-30 edits to the reports to get them to query the new sprint. Sometimes we miss changing one or two.

```
AND [Iteration Path] = [Product\R2016\December 2015 - R16 - Dev]
```

Is there a quicker and more consistent way to accomplish this?

Can you define a constant for the reports to use or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify multiple reports at a time. You have to filter "Iteration Path" field or modify the "Iteration Path" parameter manually.